# mysql query - how to find items not within certain dates

Tags: mysql, sql, cakephp

I'm pretty useless at SQL it seems and I'm trying to figure out what is the correct query to use.

I have a table Items and a table Reservations. An item can have many reservations and reservations are made between two dates.

I'm trying to create a search query which will return all the Items which don't have reservations between two user inputted dates.

the SQL I have at the minute looks like:

```
SELECT `Item`.`id`, `Item`.`user_id`, `Item`.`name`, `Item`.`description`, `User`.`id`, `User`.`username`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`email` 
FROM `database`.`items` AS `Item` 
LEFT JOIN `database`.`reservations` AS `ReservationJoin` ON (`ReservationJoin`.`item_id` = `Item`.`id` AND `ReservationJoin`.`start` >= '2013-07-17' and `ReservationJoin`.`finnish` <= '2013-07-20') 
LEFT JOIN `database`.`users` AS `User` ON (`Item`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) 
WHERE ((`Item`.`name` LIKE '%projector%') OR (`Item`.`description` LIKE '%projector%') 
AND `ReservationJoin`.`id` IS NULL 
LIMIT 10
```

I'm doing this in cakephp 2.3 so the code looks like:

```
$this->paginate = array(
      "conditions" => array(
        "or" => array(
          "Item.name LIKE" => '%'.$projector.'%',
          "Item.description LIKE" => '%'.$projector.'%',
        ),
        "ReservationJoin.id" => null,
      ),
      "joins" => array(
        array(
          "table" => "reservations",
          "alias" => "ReservationJoin",
          "type" => "LEFT",
          "conditions" => array(
            "ReservationJoin.item_id = Item.id",
            "ReservationJoin.checkin >= '{$start}' and ReservationJoin.checkout <= '{$finnish}'",
          )
        )
      ),
      "limit"=>10
    );
    $data = $this->paginate('Item');
```

This isn't working and I think it's to do with the join not excluding the reservations properly. But I've not been able to figure out what the correct mysql is. Can a kind soul tell me what I should be using?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it may be easier for you in CakePHP to put all of the conditions in a WHERE clause. (This could also be done with some OUTER JOINs but it may be difficult to transcribe into CakePHP)

```
    SELECT id, user_id, name, description
    FROM items
    WHERE ((name LIKE '%projector%') OR (description LIKE '%projector%'))
    AND NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM reservations
    WHERE items.id = reservations.item_id
    AND (
    '2013-07-17' BETWEEN start and finnish
    OR
    '2013-07-20' BETWEEN start and finnish
    OR 
    start BETWEEN '2013-07-17' AND '2013-07-20'));
```

Or, using the same logic the WHERE clause can be cleaned up to be

```
    SELECT id, user_id, name, description
    FROM items
    WHERE ((name LIKE '%projector%') OR (description LIKE '%projector%'))
    AND NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM reservations
    WHERE items.id = reservations.item_id
    AND NOT(
    '2013-07-17' > finnish
    OR
    '2013-07-20' < start
    ));
```

Comment: Any idea how to set this up in cakephp for a paginate call? I'm struggling to figure it out for myself.

Comment: I think I finally figured out how to turn your answer into cakephp and it looks like it works fine :) Happy Daze. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If something has a reservation between two dates, then one of the following is true:

1. It has a start date between the dates
2. It has an end date between the dates
3. It has a start date before the earlier date and an end date after the second one

The following query uses this logic in a `having` clause.  The approach is to aggregate at the item level and ensure that the three above conditions are true:

```
SELECT i.`id`, i.`user_id`, i.`name`, i.`description`
FROM `database`.`items`i LEFT JOIN
     `database`.`reservations` r
     ON r.`item_id` = i.`id`
WHERE ((i.`name` LIKE '%projector%') OR (i.`description` LIKE '%projector%')
group by i.id
having max(start between '2013-07-17' and '2013-07-20') = 0 and
       max(finish between '2013-07-17' and '2013-07-20') = 0 and
       max(start < '2013-07-17' and finished > '2013-07-20') = 0
LIMIT 10;
```

Note that none matches are returned, because the conditions are treated as false when `start` and `ned` are NULL.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately having group by clauses apparently breaks the pagination in cakephp. Is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
SELECT `Item`.`id`, `Item`.`user_id`, `Item`.`name`, `Item`.`description`, `User`.`id`, `User`.`username`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`email` 
FROM `database`.`items` AS `Item` 
LEFT JOIN `database`.`reservations` AS `ReservationJoin` ON (`ReservationJoin`.`item_id` = `Item`.`id`) 
LEFT JOIN `database`.`users` AS `User` ON (`Item`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) 
WHERE ((`Item`.`name` LIKE '%projector%') OR (`Item`.`description` LIKE '%projector%')) 
AND `ReservationJoin`.`start` >= '2013-07-17' 
AND `ReservationJoin`.`finnish` <= '2013-07-20'
AND `ReservationJoin`.`id` IS NULL 
LIMIT 10
```

i.e just move the date clauses into the WHERE clause as oppose to being in the JOIN CLAUSE

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I like the idea of this one because it looks the easiest to translate into cakephp. So I've managed to do that and the SQL produced is as you suggested. But this returns no results no matter what dates (or no dates) are used. Any ideas what could be happening?